# How to delete document with multiple index in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I have sample data like below.

```
Data_id Name    Destination
224345565   HCM South VietNam
456566666   HN  North VietNam
```

   Index: Sample_1

[sample_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbY57.png)
[sample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiGKT.png)

```
Data_id Food    Drink
224345565   Banh Mi Milk Coffee
456566666   Bun Cha Nuoc quac
```

   Index Sample_2

[sample_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYlqx.png)
[sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqbSG.png)
I want to delete HCM name in first table and the data related with the same Data_id in Sample_2 also deleted. How can I do it?
DELETE /sample_1, sample_2/_doc/224345565 ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [delete by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html), to delete some specific documents (based on a condition) from multiple indexes.

```
POST /sample1,sample2/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Data_id": 224345565
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Josley please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Hi @ESCoder, I try with your answer, the data in sample2 was deleted but data in a sample is still exists!

Comment: @Josley have you added both the index in the post-call -> `POST /sample1,sample2/_delete_by_query` ? Because I tried it, and this query is working fine

Comment: @Josley can you please share the query which you are using along with the POST API call

Comment: Could you look through the new image in the post! The other example is about data in 2 different indexs.

Comment: @Josley The query given in the answer above, will work for this case also. Have you tried the query I posted above in the answer ?